# R: C++ Optimization flag when using the inline package

Tags: c++, r, inline, rcpp

In R when using the cxxfunction from the [inline package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/inline/index.html), how does one change the optimization flag for the cpp compiler?

By default, on my machine, it compiles with `-g -O2`. But I would like to use the `-O3` optimization to gain speed. I use the `Rcpp` plugin if that makes any difference.

I have tried creating my own plugin, and I have tried to set the different arguments of the cxxfunction but nothing worked.

I guess one option would be to compile it using `R CMD SHLIB` instead of using `cxxfunction`. But Rcpp recommends the use of `inline` because most of their test cases are using it.

thanks for your help, let me know if you need any clarification

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

1. The best solution is to modify this **for all usage by R** so create *e.g.* a file `~/.R/Makevars` and set CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS, ... there.  This will affect all use by `R CMD INSTALL ...`, `R CMD SHLIB ...` etc pp and as `cxxfunction()` from inline uses it, it works here too.
2. Specific to inline and Rcpp:  modify the plugin, that's why it is a plugin system. See `Rcpp:::Rcpp.plugin.maker()`.
3. Switch back from `cxxfunction()` to `cfunction()`, hence do not use a plugin and set all arguments manually.

Needless to say, I like option 1 and use it myself.

*Edit:* A fourth (and crude !!) method I used to use in the past is to edit `$R_HOME/Makeconf` and/or `Makeconf.site`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming and accepting, you may also give this an 'up-vote' by clicking on the upwards facing triangle :)

Comment: I would, but apparently my reputation is too low (below 15) :-)

Comment: you could increase @tibo's reputation by up-voting their question. ;-)

Comment: Very fair point :)   Especially as I do acknowledge that `~/.R/Makevars` seems somewhat under-documented for R.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It would really help if you gave the syntax for setting CFLAGS or CXXFLAGS with an example line.

Comment: hi @markgalassi: Exactly what are you after (with this nine your answer)? Did you try `cat $(Rscript -e 'cat(file.path( R.home("etc"), "Makeconf" ))')` (_i.e._ use R to tell you where `RHOME` is, then look at `etc/Makeconf` therein.  It has your default values. In `~/.R/Makevars` you just override / mod as needed.

Comment: I was just hoping for an example of a line that can go into the Makevars file.  Your idea to find the system versions of those files was very useful - the shell snippet did not work on my system, but a "locate Makevars | grep R" did and I was able to find examples; thanks!

Comment: Ok. Note the difference between `Makeconf` (in R's own `etc/`) and `Makevars` (in packages).  For the latter you have several thousand examples at CRAN, and you can _e.g._ search them via https://github.com/search?q=org%3Acran+Makevars&type=code

Comment: I use `withr::with_makevars` if I only need to temporarily set CPPFLAGS

Comment: Sure, one can almost always wrap everything in yet another layer.  At the end of the day I suspect this just sets the environment variable for you.  Up to you to use `Sys.setenv()` from base R, or something that calls it for you.  Nice to have choices but it all ends in the same machine room: `R` calling `make` calling your compiler ...

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a hack. Write a little wrapper program (also called cpp) which calls the real cpp and passes all arguments to it as is except that it passes -O3 for optimization. Then make sure your program occurs first in the executable path resolution for R.

Comment: But heck it works; we've all done similar things to get the job done.