# How to set g++ compiler flags using Rcpp and inline?

Tags: c++, r, inline, rcpp

I want to set `-std=c++0x`, using Rcpp with inline.

I saw [R: C++ Optimization flag when using the inline package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789673/r-c-optimization-flag-when-using-the-inline-package) but don't want to make a system-wide change, so I was trying option 2 in Dirk's answer.

I tried:

```
settings=getPlugin("Rcpp")
settings$Makevars[length(settings$Makevars)+1] = "CXXFLAGS = $(CXXFLAGS) -std=c++0x"
fun=cxxfunction(signature(x_ ="numeric"),src,plugin="Rcpp",settings=settings,verbose=2);
```

But the verbose output shows it is ignoring that. I also tried with CFLAGS, and without including existing value, but no effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some source code study, and a hint from Dirk Eddelbuettel, I've worked this out:

```
settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS='-std=c++0x'
```

You can set `PKG_CPPFLAGS` the same way.

Here is a complete and more robust example:

```
library(inline)

src='
using namespace Rcpp;
std::vector<const char*> test={"Hello","World","!!!"};
return wrap(test);
'

settings=getPlugin("Rcpp")
settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS=paste('-std=c++0x',settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS,sep=' ')
fun=cxxfunction(signature(),src,plugin="Rcpp",settings=settings)

Sys.unsetenv('PKG_CXXFLAGS')

print(fun())
```

The `paste()` makes sure if there were any settings already in the plugin then they are preserved.

The `unsetenv()` is something `cxxfunction` should already be doing (IMHO). Currently it will add variables to the environment, but not remove them after. So, without the `unsetenv()` call, if you later ran `cxxfunction` again, but with all defaults, any `CXXFLAGS` you had earlier set would get used. This might not matter, or it might give surprising results. (Imagine if your were using `PKG_CXXFLAGS` to set `-Wall -Werror` for your own code, but later code links to a 3rd party library and refuses to compile with those options.)