# Develop R package for different platform

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

I develope a package using Rcpp, cpp include "windows.h" library, but this package is not available on Linux, so I decided to achieve the same function using reticulate package to call python package, how should I make package detect installed on which platform ?
If on Windows platform, installing my package will compile cpp file , if on **Linux** , installing my package will not compile cpp file but using my r code inside.
For example:

Windows:

```
myfunction<-function(){
   .Call(C++ function)
}
```

And also avoid compile cpp file in src folder or there will be error : "no windows.h library"

Linux:

```
myfunction<-function(){
    library(reticulate)
    import(py_package)
}
```

Comment: I would first try to make the C++ code platform independent using suitable `ifdef __WIN32` etc. What functionality from `windows.h` do you require? Note that it can be problematic to use it in conjunction with `R.h`, c. f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588765/using-rcpp-with-windows-specific-includes

Comment: I use keybd_event function

Comment: Interesting. I cannot imagine why one would want to simulate a key press within an R package. However, for Linux you could look at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/uinput.html.

Comment: mmm.....for those people who only knows R but other languages ? And make R more comprehensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can rethink your approach and provide a C++ solution on platforms other than Windows too?   But in short you can the following:

#### In R

Use eg  `if (Sys.info()[["sysname"]] == "Windows")` to test for windows, and in the else branch call the replacement

#### In C/C++

Use `#define` tests such as `#if defined(_WIN32)` to bracket the `#include <windows>`, and also the body of your function.  Just return eg nothing on other platforms.

*Many* packages do things depending on the platform they are on. Feel free to look around at existing sources -- CRAN has over 12k and GitHub is treasure trove too.

Comment: You can allow the code to compile on Linux. That is the only way to go as you cannot alter what `install.packages()` does -- but you can influence and alter how your package is set up and _you can make it installable_.  Start with reading more of "Writing R Extensions" particular towards the end of it.