# sourceCpp using O3 and other options

Tags: r, rcpp

I am using testing codes written in RCpp on both Windows 7 and Linux (Ubuntu Trusty 14.04) and I noticed that `sourceCpp` uses g++ options such as `-O2`. I would like to change it to `-O3` (more optimizations) and also try out Intel optimizations such as `-mtune=corei7-avx` and/or `-march=corei7-avx`  to see if there is any improvements in speed.

How can I change the default options of `sourceCpp` to allow this?

Comment: Please see Dirk's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789673/r-c-optimization-flag-when-using-the-inline-package?rq=1 (in particular, re: `~/.R/Makevars`)

Comment: @KevinUshey, thanks. quick question, under Windows and under Linux, where is the `.R` directory located? Or does one have to create a `.R` directory first and then keep the `Makevars` file there?

Comment: Look for the value of `HOME` eg via `Sys.getenv("HOME")`. You may not have set it yet on Windows, but if you set it (google for how) R will honor.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, also what about Windows? do I also create a `.R` directory in Windows there?

Comment: Yes *of course*. My answer was specifically for your Windows use. Other OS always have `$HOME`.  So yes, create the dir and file.