# RcppEigen functions are very fast with sourceCpp but very slow when compiled as a package

Tags: c++, r, eigen, rcpp, rcppeigen

I've written an RcppEigen package with extensive OpenMP usage, all of which is in a single .cpp file.

When I compile the code using `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` everything is extremely fast -- amazing.

When I compile using `devtools::document()` and run the same function it's terribly slow -- not amazing.

I suspect this is something to do with my Makevars file and/or compiler optimization. I've seen a few questions on this topic ([Overriding system defaults for C++ compilation flags from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341106/overriding-system-defaults-for-c-compilation-flags-from-r), [R: C++ Optimization flag when using the inline package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789673/r-c-optimization-flag-when-using-the-inline-package)).

This is my makevars file:

```
CXXFLAGS=-O3 -fopenmp
CXX_STD = CXX11
```

Comment: Run it by hand (`R CMD INSTALL ...`) and pay attention to the compilation flag. You may want `-fopenmp` also in `CXX11FLAGS` and `CXX14FLAGS`.  You could also check what other packages using OpenMP do.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks. Adding `PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)` to `Makevars` fixed the OpenMP issue, but I'm still fighting the `-O2` vs. `-O3` issue. Yes, I can change this in my `~.R/Makevars` file locally, but that doesn't guarantee the user on the other end will compile with `-O3`. My understanding is it is not possible to guarantee `-O3` compiler optimization for an R package?

Comment: For a CRAN package, you can set whatever you want _portably_ via a `configure` file that detects the compiler and then, conditional on the compiler, "does the right thing". CRAN is cool with that.  For a non-CRAN package you can do whatever you want.  All this has, of course, been discussed numerous times before as you are not the first person write a package with C++ who is interested about performance.